# How can i fix "Failed to Compile" in npm for react application developing?

Tags: reactjs

Its my first test app. but why its not compiled.
i couldn't figure it out. Can anyone explain please.

[image: image of cmd]

[image: image of cmd1]

[image: index.html file]

[image: app.jsx file]

[image: main.js file]

[image: package.json file]

[image: webpack.config.js file]

Answer (score 1):

Your index.html file is referencing "index.js", but from the screenshots you have provided it looks as though you don't have this, but instead you have "main.js".

Hence change "index.html" to reference "main.js" i.e.

```
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Also there's a typo in main.js, change "ducument" to "document".

Comment: I got it . Thank you Sir .